# How to fix "Null exception" when seeding and initialising the database in asp.net core (Entity Framework)

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core

I'm trying to seed my data for the first time run, using the configure function in Startup.cs

```
public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IHostingEnvironment env, ILoggerFactory loggerFactory)
    {
       .
       .
        app.SeedData();
    }
```

the `app.SeedData();` then calls the SeedData function in DataSeeder.cs to initialise the ApplicatonDbContext.

```
public static class DataSeeder
{
    public static async void SeedData(this IApplicationBuilder app)
    {
        var dbManager = app.ApplicationServices.GetService<ApplicationDbContext>();
        dbManager.Database.Migrate();

        Brand Addiction;
        Addiction = new Brand()
        {
            BrandName = "Addiction"
        };
        dbManager.Brands.Add(Addiction);
        dbManager.SaveChanges();
        return;
    }
}
```

When the code tries to run the `dbManager.Database.Migrate();`, it throws a NullReferenceException saying that dbManager is null. I tried putting a breakpoint on the first line of ApplicationDbContext.cs, seems like it doesn't run it. Any ways on how to fix it?

I've seen others using `app.ApplicationServices.GetRequiredService<ApplicationDbContext>();` instead of `app.ApplicationServices.GetService<ApplicationDbContext>();`. I tried changing that and got an InvalidOperationException instead, saying "No service for type 'BrandTest.Data.ApplicationDbContext' has been registered."

My ApplicationDbContext.cs code btw

```
using BrandTest.Models;
using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore;
using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Metadata.Internal;
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace BrandTest.Data
{
public class ApplicationDbContext : DbContext
{
    public DbSet<Brand> Brands { get; set; }

    protected override void OnConfiguring(DbContextOptionsBuilder optionsBuilder)
    {
        optionsBuilder.UseSqlServer(@"Server=DESKTOP-ABCDE\SQLEXPRESS;Database=PetStoreDB;Trusted_Connection=True;MultipleActiveResultSets=True");
        base.OnConfiguring(optionsBuilder);
    }
```

Comment: Share us your `Startup.cs`

Answer (score 0):

U have to add your context to DI in your Startup class (same class, where u have Configure() method)

```
// This method gets called by the runtime. Use this method to add services to the container.
        public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
        {
...
            services.AddScoped<ApplicationDbContext>();
...
        }
```

this is Startup class from one of my projects:

```
public class Startup
{
    public Startup(IConfiguration configuration, IHostingEnvironment env)
    {
        Configuration = configuration;
        var builder = new ConfigurationBuilder()
            .SetBasePath(env.ContentRootPath)
            .AddJsonFile("appsettings.json", false, true)
            .AddJsonFile($"appsettings.{env.EnvironmentName}.json", true)
            .AddEnvironmentVariables();

        Configuration = builder.Build();
    }

    public static IConfiguration Configuration { get; private set; }

    // This method gets called by the runtime. Use this method to add services to the container.
    public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
    {
        services.AddMvc().SetCompatibilityVersion(CompatibilityVersion.Version_2_1);

        services.AddOptions<ActivationServiceOptions>(Configuration);

        services.AddScoped<ActivationServiceContext>();
        services.AddOptions<ActivationServiceContextOptions>(Configuration);

        services.AddOptions<KeysProviderOptions>(Configuration);
        services.AddScoped<IEncryptor, Encryptor>();

        LandingLoggingStartup.ConfigureServices(services, Configuration);
    }

    // This method gets called by the runtime. Use this method to configure the HTTP request pipeline.
    public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IHostingEnvironment env)
    {
        if (env.IsDevelopment())
            app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();
        else
            app.UseHsts();

        LandingLoggingStartup.Configure(app);
        app.UseMvc();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

> > InvalidOperationException instead, saying "No service for type 'BrandTest.Data.ApplicationDbContext' has been registered."

For this error message, you need to register your dbcontext in `Startup.cs` like

```
services.AddDbContext<ApplicationDbContext>(options =>
{
    options.UseSqlServer(
        Configuration.GetConnectionString("MySqlConnection"));
});
```

And you could not resolve the service from root provider, change `DataSeeder` like

```
public static class DataSeeder
{
    public static async void SeedData(this IApplicationBuilder app)
    {
        var dbManager = app.ApplicationServices.CreateScope().ServiceProvider.GetRequiredService<ApplicationDbContext>();
        dbManager.Database.Migrate();
        Brand Addiction;
        Addiction = new Brand()
        {
            BrandName = "Addiction"
        };
        dbManager.Brands.Add(Addiction);
        dbManager.SaveChanges();
        return;
    }
}
```